# Plotting interpolated data on map with irregular boundaries in R

Tags: r, mask, shapefile

I am having trouble plotting my results on map with irregular boundaries. I have interpolated climate data using IDW method as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gstat)
library(sp)
library(maptools)


df<-my_data

coordinates(df) = ~X + Y
x.range <- as.numeric(c(20.375, 31.375))
y.range <- as.numeric(c(52.375, 61.375))

grd2 <- expand.grid(X = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 0.01), Y = seq(from = y.range[1], to = y.range[2], by = 0.01))
coordinates(grd2) <- ~X + Y
gridded(grd2) <- TRUE
plot(grd2, cex = 1.5, col = "grey")
points(df, pch = 1, col = "red", cex = 1)

df2<-my_data
colnames(df2)<- c("ID", "lon", "lat", "vari")
idw2 <- idw(formula = vari ~ 1, locations = df, newdata = grd2)
idw.output2 = as.data.frame(idw2)
names(idw.output2)[1:3] <- c("lon", "lat", "var1.pred")
```

Now I want to put the mask on these idw results. In the past, I have always used only the boundary of one country without any problems. Code:

```
mymap <- readOGR("countryy.shp", layer="countryy")
summary(mymap)
wgsmap <- spTransform(mymap, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))
wgsmap.contour <- fortify(wgsmap)

library(raster)

idw.r <- rasterFromXYZ(idw.output2[, c("lon", "lat", "var1.pred")])
idw.crp <- crop(idw.r, wgsmap)
idw.msk <- mask(idw.crp, wgsmap)
idw.msk.dfr <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(idw.msk))
names(idw.msk.dfr)[1:2] <- c("lon", "lat")

#result
ggplot() + geom_tile(data = idw.msk.dfr, alpha = 0.8, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = round(var1.pred, 0))) + scale_fill_gradient(low = "cyan", high = "orange") + geom_path(data = wgsmap.contour, aes(long, lat, group = group), colour = "grey") + geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = lon, y = lat), shape = 18, colour = "red")
```

Now I need to put on a mask with a new boundaries including several countries:

x.range <- as.numeric(c(20.375, 31.375))
y.range <- as.numeric(c(52.375, 61.375))

I am not sure how to do it. Should I somehow trim ESRI shapefile of the whole world according to my coordinate rectangle? Or maybe I can use a simple map from ggspatial:

```
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library(ggspatial)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)

europe <- ggplot(data = world) +geom_sf() + coord_sf(xlim = c(20.375, 31.375), ylim = c(52.375, 61.375), expand = FALSE)
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: Your problem has too many steps for trying to helping you without having a reproducible example which includes part of your input data. Please, consider finding out the way to share it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added my variables from the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was sold using package ‘GADMTools’.

```
joinmap <- gadm_sp_loadCountries(c("RUS","LTU","LVA", "EST", "FIN", "POL", "BLR"),  basefile = "./")

studyarea <- gadm_crop(joinmap, xmin=20.375, ymin=52.375, xmax=31.375, ymax=61.375)

gadm_exportToShapefile(studyarea, "path for shapefile")
```